# assigning based on more than 2 conditions in R to reassign data values for a vector

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have rather large meteorological data sets that look something like:

```
year  month day hour min sec temp RH Rad
```

I need to convert the day to the sequential day of year, e.g:

- jan 1 is day 0
- feb 1 is day 31
- march 1 is day 59 (in non leap years)
- April 1 is 90, etc.

Data are stored in a data frame, say `met_dat`, with `met_dat$year`,  `met_dat$day`, etc.

I'd like to assign the yd based on the month, i.e.,

```
if met_dat$month==0, /*this is the code for january*/
then 
met_dat$yd<-met_dat$day,

else if met_dat$month==1, /*this is the code for february*/
then
met_dat$yd<-met_dat$day+30

else if met_dat$month==2,
then
met_dat$yd<-met_dat$day+58

etc, for the remaining months.
```

I've tried nesting ifelse statements as:

```
met_dat$yd<-ifelse( (met_dat$month==0),met_dat$yd<-met_dat$day,
           (ifelse( (met_dat$month==1), met_dat$yd<-met_dat$day+30,
              (ifelse( (met_dat$month==2), met_dat$yd<-met_dat$day+58, NA) )))
```

My real code has all 12 months, but 12 or three, this doesn't work...it assigns incorrect values for met_dat$yd, sometimes near correct, but never correct for all months.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your data to `Date` using `as.Date`, thus turning it into an integer representation. Then simply subtract an epoch (reference) date from each value. Like this:

```
x <- data.frame(
  year = 2012,
  month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr"),
  day = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2)
)

xx <- with(x, as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep="-"), format="%Y-%b-%d"))

xx
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02" "2012-02-01" "2012-03-01" "2012-04-01" "2012-04-02"

xx - as.Date("2012-01-01")
Time differences in days
[1]  0  1 31 60 91 92
```